# What's the best way to find intersection in 2 arrays and what algorithmic complexity does each of the ways have?

Tags: javascript

1. with `some`

```js
function test(arr1,arr2){
  return arr1.filter(el1=>{
    return arr2.some(el2=>{
      return el2 === el1
    })
  })
}

console.log(test([1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6]))
```

2. with `includes`

```js
function test(arr1,arr2){
  return arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item));
}
    
console.log(test([1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6]))
```

Maybe there are better way to solve this task?

Comment: They have the same complexity.  They are of equivalent goodness.

Comment: If these arrays were large, I would suggest using Set's.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: These both have `O(n*m)` complexity, but `O(n+m)` is achievable

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to save the numbers in the first array.

Then, iterate over the second array using [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and add each item that is in the set:

```js
function getIntersection(arr1 = [], arr2 = []) {
  const set = new Set(arr1);
  const intersection = [];
  arr2.forEach(num => {
    if(set.has(num)) intersection.push(num);
  });
  return intersection;
}

console.log( getIntersection([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for one array and filter the other one.

Basically you need one loop for every array.

```js
function test(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(arr2));
}

console.log(test([1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6]))
```